# mvc 3 session and authorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authorize-attribute

My site is open to all but i have a controller with some method that only the manager with the user and password can enter. I'm saving the bool `IsManager` in a `session`.
I would like to use the authorize attribute to block whom ever `IsManager == false`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**First define an `ActionFilter`:**

```
public class TheFilter: ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
        var session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
        if ((bool?)session["IsManager"] == true)
            return;

        //Redirect him to somewhere.
        var redirectTarget = new RouteValueDictionary
             {{"action", "{ActionName}"}, {"controller", "{ControllerName}"}};
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTarget);
   }
}
```

**Then use it above the restricted Action(or controller):**

```
//[TheFilter]
public class ManagersController : Controller
{
    [TheFilter]
    public ActionResult Foo()
    {
        ...
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Security filters should implement IAuthorizationFilter - which run before action filters. You are opening up a security hole buy using the action filter. See my MSDN article on filters http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx Better to override the admin controller's OnAuthorization filter.

Comment: @Rick.Anderson-at-Microsoft.com I believe its the case as well with an auth filter you need to be extra careful so you don't hit a caching issue too and content is returned for another user, no?

Comment: @Rick.Anderson-at-Microsoft.com. I Read your post. Couldn't see any security holes that I'm opening, can you give an example?

Comment: @gdoron Not worked for me. I load page using partialview via AJAX and this approach not worked :( Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

To keep this in line with ASP.NET security you should add the IsManager role to your membership/role system, then add that user to the role. No hacking required then and you can use the built in Authorize attribute.

Are you using the built in membership providers? If so this would be a snap.

Comment: Right now I don't use anything like membership providers. My site is public beside a small part which is a manager only controller that i want to limit access to...

Comment: Then you can simply create the IPrinciple on Application_AuthenticateRequest and populate the roles there so you can use the Authorize attribute. This way if you ever move to a membership system, you won't need to change any attributes (as you would in the case of a custom attribute)