# Authorization for a controller in MVC 3 based on Session value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am storing Boolean value in session if a user is Admin or not after some business logic. This logic implemented in home page itself. Now I need to authorize admin controller based on this session value. Any suggestion or reference link please.

```
Session["Admin"] = true;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mvc 3 session and authorizeAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809703/mvc-3-session-and-authorizeattribute)

Comment: @Izzy: the linked answer is disputable, what should be an authorization filter is implemented as an action filter. It promotes an inaccurate approach then.

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla: Thanks for your suggestion. I am a beginner in MVC. If possible, can you please refer any link where I can get correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in the controller:

```
 Session["Admin"] = true;
 if (!(bool)Session["Admin"])
 {
    //Do the appropriate action here like redirect 
    return RedirectToAction("NoRights");
 }
```